# Reducing operator parallelism impact on job performance

Tags: apache-flink

I started wondering what would be the use-case related to performance of reducing parallelism of particular operator in the flink job. I understand all technicality how parallelism relates to number of subtasks and slots etc.

Let's imagine a job with three tasks i.e Source -> Agg -> Sink

If I configure flink to use for example 32 slots than what would be the performance difference if I assign the same parallelism to all 3 tasks ie. 32 versus assigning Source reduced parallelism of 10? 
My understanding is that less record would be read from the source (i.e less consumer threads) but this would result in degraded performance? Reducing parallelism of source doesn't mean I could even higher parallelism on cpu demanding operator like assign (32-10) + 32 = 54 parallelism (I know flink wouldn't allow that if 32 slots are available)

In the case where the source produces too many records back pressure would kick in and slow down source?

Comment: Is there a keyBy in front of the aggregation?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - very likely. It's a general question - however if answer depends on `keyBy` than yes!

Comment: @DavidAnderson I now understand your point! 
`In case of non-keyed streams, your original stream will not be split into multiple logical streams and all the windowing logic will be performed by a single task, i.e. with parallelism of 1.`
Yes definitely. Even if there is not natural key I would generate a random once so that records can be processed in parallel!

Comment: That statement you quoted is only true if you use the window operator. In general you can have parallel pipelines without keying, but most aggregations only make sense if they are either global, or done on a per-key basis.

Answer (score 0):

When a pipeline consists solely of forward connections -- in other words, if there are no keyBy or rebalance operations, and the parallelism remains constant -- then the operators will be chained together, avoiding the costs of network communication and ser/de. This has considerable performance benefits.

Typically a pipeline consisting of

```
source -> agg -> sink
```

will really be doing

```
source -> keyBy + agg -> sink
```

which means that there's already going to be networking and ser/de between the source and the aggregation operator. But if there were no keyBy, then changing the parallelism between the source and the agg would be imposing the cost of that network shuffle / rebalance.

With no keyBy, you would simply have

```
source + agg + sink
```

all running in one thread.

But with a keyBy, so long as the parallelism remains unchanged between the aggregator and sink, this pipeline will really be executed as

```
source -> keyBy + agg + sink
```

because the aggregator and sink will be chained together in the same task (and thus run in the same thread).

Having the parallelism be 32 at the source should improve throughput out of the source so long as the source has at least 32 partitions or shards.

But exactly how this is all going to behave depends on a bunch of things. If the keys are unbalanced, or if the sink is slow, or if aggregator has very bursty behavior, these things can all impact throughput and latency.

If the source is producing records faster than the aggregation + sink can process them, then the agg + sink task will backpressure the source, and it will only read as fast as the rest of the pipeline can handle. While this is sort of okay, it is preferable to avoid constant backpressure, because backpressure can lead to checkpoint timeouts. So in this situation you may want to reduce the parallelism at the source, or increase the parallelism for the agg + sink task.